# Are samples dependent or independent, paired or unpaired?

Tags: statistical-significance, paired-data, independence

An animal performs a task in a T-maze. Sometimes he chooses the right part of the maze (right trials) and sometimes left(left trials).

I want to know if there are differences in firing rate of one neuron between these two types of trials: left and right. So, my independent variable is left vs right trials.

For example, I have 7 values of firing rate corresponding to 7 left trials and 10 values of firing rate corresponding to 10 right trials.
Since all firing rates correspond to the same neuron I thought samples were dependent and paired. By reading on Internet, I thought I may be wrong. Can anyone help me?

And, what stats would you use to check differences between left and right trials?
Thanks,
Ana

Comment: Can you explain what is *left and right trials*?

Comment: Left and right trials correspond to the independent variable: animals perform a task on a maze and in some trials they choose right and in other trials they choose left.

Comment: Please add that information as an edit to the original question, many people do not read comments. And, what you explain seems to tell me that *left* and *right* here is part of the result, and not really different kinds of trials? Your post could benefit from an extended explication!

Comment: One way to view your experiment is that it consists of a sequence of 17 trials.  In each trial two values are observed: firing rate and direction of turn.  Since these trials are all for the same animal, you can justify making inferences about that animal, but it would be difficult (on a statistical basis alone) to generalize from that animal to any larger population. It is a matter for the data to determine whether this sequence of observations can be considered independent or not: plausibly, there could be some "carry over" effect from one state of the neuron to the next.

Answer (score 1):

Your data can**not** be **paired**, as your animal can choose each time at random which side it uses and therefore you might end up with different numbers of observations per individual for left and right side trials. In the most extreme case, an animal chooses only right trials and you will only observe right side data. 
For this, you will require some form of mixed effects model structure, where the individual from which you observe the trials is a model layer.

Unless you assume a learning behaviour of the test animal, the trials are **independent**. If you have such a **learning behaviour**, then your trials are **dependent** and you will require an additional variable counting that this is the i-th trial on the left or j-th trial on the right side and trial (i+1) on the left and (j+1) on the right side will have dependence on the the trials before.

Comment: There is not learning. The animals learn the task before I collect the data. If they couldn't choose between left and right, would the data be paired?

Comment: Then your trials are independent.

Comment: After reading your answers, I understand that trials are independent for both cases: chosen and not chosen trials. Am I right?

Comment: Unless the outcome of one trial affects the choice or outcome of the following trial (= as long as the animals chooses left vs. right at random), they are independent. If it starts developing 'preferences' and starts out with 6 left trials, afterwards choosing only right trials because it gets better rewards or less demanding tasks, the independence is not valid.

Comment: Data is not normal. I checked normality of data with Shapiro test, histograms shapes and q-q plots. Could I use a Mann-Withney U-test or a Wilcoxon rank-sum test to check differences between left and right trials?

Comment: I would not use a non-parametric rank beased test for such small sample sizes, as you described them. In my experience, the power of the test is typically too small for detecting anything, unless the effects are large enough to already be detectable with a simple graphical exploration.

Comment: When I use the Wilcoxon rank-sum on Python, I find many p values<0.05 in many neurons so it seems it detects well significant differences. Do you think is the right test to be used?

Comment: If you do this for a lot of neurons, you will have to correct for multiple testing!

Comment: If I apply the Wilcoxon rank-sum test for every neuron, so I get a p value for every neuron. Do I need to correct for multiple testing? What's the procedure to do it?